# How to handle null if an element may not exist when returning from List<> method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this method:

```
public static List<PointElement> retrievePoints(
    FullResponse responseWrapper) {
  List<PointElement> pointsList =
      responseWrapper.getFullBreakdownResult().getPoints();
  return pointsList.stream()
      .map(
          point ->
              new PointElement(
                  null,
                  null,
                  point.getRefNum(),
                  point.getPointCode()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

It's possible that `pointsList` might be a null value. Currently if that's the case I get a `NullPointerException` at the `return`.

I thought maybe I could change it to:

```
public static Optional<List<PointElement>> retrievePoints(
    FullResponse responseWrapper) {
  Optional<List<PointElement>> pointsList =
      responseWrapper.getFullBreakdownResult().getPoints();
  return pointsList.stream()
      .map(
          point ->
              new PointElement(
                  null,
                  null,
                  point.getRefNum(),
                  point.getPointCode()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

That causes other issues in that methods `point.getRefNum()` and `point.getPointCode()` cannot be resolved?

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: One option - on detection of `pointsList` is null, then return an empty `PointElement` list.

Comment: This question cannot be answered until you first explain what `null` would _mean_. When `getPoints()` returns `null`, what does that imply? If it implies 'no points exist', then __your code is currently wrong__ - it should then return an empty list instead of `null`. If it means something else, then what is that, and why is it correct to act the same way as an empty list (do nothing)? Generally, either [A] this question is moot (as an empty list is returned, which you can just `stream()` as normal), or [B] The NPE is correct - you _want_ `retrievePoints` to crash, as the state isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

`Optional<Collection<T>>` is generally frowned upon. Return an empty collection instead.

```
public static List<PointElement> retrievePoints(
    FullResponse responseWrapper) {
  List<PointElement> pointsList =
      responseWrapper.getFullBreakdownResult().getPoints();
  if (pointsList == null) return Collections.emptyList();

  return pointsList.stream()
      .map(
          point ->
              new PointElement(
                  null,
                  null,
                  point.getRefNum(),
                  point.getPointCode()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need filter the data inside in your stream, using filter is perfect for this case.

```java
        public static List<PointElement> retrievePoint(FullResponse responseWrapper){
        List<PointElement> pointsList = responseWrapper.getFullBreakdownResult().getPoints();
        if(pointsList == null)return Collections.emptyList();
        return pointsList.stream().filter(point -> points!=null).map(point ->newPointElement(null,null,point.getRefNum(),point.getPointCode())).collections(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

If you prefer use Objects from java.util, to validate if a Object is null, like:

```java
if(Objects.isNull(pointsList)) return Collections.emptyList();
```

And you can use in a stream like:

```java
return list.stream().filter(e-> Objects.nonNull(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or

```java
return list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

As *@knittl* has pointed out in his answer, wrapping a Collection with an `Optional` doesn't make sense.

`Optional` was designed as a container of nullable data, and you can safely interact with the container regardless whether it contains a value or not. But Collections and arrays by their nature are also **containers of data**, they can represent the absence of data by being empty and that can be verified without any issues.

Therefore, `List` would be sufficient as a return value.

Since you're not treating the case when `responseWrapper.getFullBreakdownResult().getPoints()` doesn't return a data as a normal event and not going to throw an exception or log this information, then you can use Java 9 method [`Stream.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) to generate a stream pipeline from the nullable source.

```
public static List<PointElement> retrievePoints(FullResponse responseWrapper) {
    
    return Stream.ofNullable(responseWrapper.getFullBreakdownResult().getPoints())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(point ->
                new PointElement(
                    null,
                    null,
                    point.getRefNum(),
                    point.getPointCode())
        )
        .toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Comment: Won't `Stream.ofNullable` here return a `Stream<List<PointElement>>` instead of the required `Stream<PointElement>`? I think you want `Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(getPoints(), emptyList()).stream()` here

Comment: @knittl Good point, amended.

Comment: @knittl Regarding `Objects.requireNonNullElseGet()`, it's also a possible option. It appears at the same language level (JDK 9), and expressive enough as well as `Stream.ofNullable`